# Chaining of promises in node js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am learning promises in nodejs.

Below is my example code

```
var Q = require('q');

Q.when(null)
 .then(function () {
      return 'kung foo';
      })
 .then(function (val) {
       console.log(val); // kung foo
      //return Q.when('panda');
     return 'panda';
    })
 .then(function (val) {
   console.log(val); // panda
   // Nothing returned
  })
  .then(function (val) {
     console.log(val == undefined); // true
   });
```

In the second "then" , whether the callback returns "return Q.when('panda');" OR 
"return 'panda';" the output is same(kung foo panda true).

I would like to know whats difference these two statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one statement returns a value (the string `'panda'`), the other statement returns a promise for that very same value (a promise resolved with the string `'panda'`).

The `then` method does by default await promises returned from a callback before resolving the outer (chained) promise with their result, but when the callback returns a plain value it will just take that.